# java : how to know from where the libraries are loaded at runtime

Tags: java, jar, shared-libraries

I have a issue where a jar file runs on one machine , but not on another machine -
[asked on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487646/running-jar-on-another-computer).

It seems some dependencies are not found on the second computer. 
My question is, is there a way to know from where the libraries are loaded (as in - to simply `System.out.println("from which directory the dependent jar is linked")`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will output a lot of information, but it includes the location of all jar files:

You can start Java with the `-verbose:class` option to debug classloader issues.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe could use `jcmd` (part of the JDK) and query the JVM which class path it was using at its startup.

```
jcmd ${pid_of_the_JVM} VM.system_properties | grep path
```

in the output have a look for the properties

```
java.class.path
sun.boot.class.path
```